# Can't launch Google Now with swipe up from home key

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

[image: This is not I want]

I googled it and found that this may be what many people were looking for but I don't know why it started to behave like this.

I do find the swiping up from home button gesture useful for me to launch Google search but somehow it stop working. There usually should be a semicircle with 'Google' on top when halfway swiping up but what I get now is a search icon that function as it will launch last used app (if swiping gesture is done in launcher) or will do nothing (when gesture done in any app other than launcher). I did not disable Google Search, reboot didn't help, and clearing cache of Google search didn't help too.

I don't know what I did to get this as a result. Any clue on what's happening? Nexus 7 2013 stock kitkat

Edit: Dolphin browser is causing this. Uninstalled it and everything's back to normal

Comment: Google Now _is_ Google Search. Are you sure on the latest version?

Comment: @AlE. Yes I know, and I'm on the latest version. But I found the root of the problem. Dolphin browser is causing it so I uninstalled it and everything is back to normal. Thanks anyway

Comment: Be sure to add that as an answer for those who encounter the same problem in the future.